# What is apc_fetch(): apc_fcntl_rdlock`?

Tags: php, windows, apc

```
Fatal error: apc_fetch(): apc_fcntl_rdlock failed errno:6 in C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\xx\xxx\api\vendor\klein\klein\Klein\Klein.php on line 500
```

What is this error? And what might causing it?

APC is enabled and here is what I get from from `phpinfo()`:

```
apc

APC Support enabled
Version 3.1.13
APC Debugging   Disabled
MMAP Support    Disabled
Locking type    File Locks
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 327136 $
Build Date  Apr 23 2014 17:21:24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC is the [Alternative PHP Cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) which is a great tool that speeds up PHP code on websites. But if you are doing local development—which you seem to be doing—you don’t need it. And it seems there [are issues with APC on Windows machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857208/apc-on-windows-iis-7-0-unstable). And the best, practical solution is to disable it completely [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358341/when-useing-php-cli-apc-crashes-apache-apc-fcntl-lock-failed-errno6).

You need to find which `php.ini` is being loaded by your setup by looking at the output of `phpinfo()`. Then comment out the line that actually loads APC which looks like this:

```
extension=apc.so
```

And comment it out like this:

```
;extension=apc.so
```

Or you can still load the `apc.so` yet disable it by setting this:

```
apc.enabled = 1
```

To this:

```
apc.enabled = 0
```

If you can’t find a line like that in `php.ini` then look for a file called `apc.ini`. On Ubuntu 12.04 it would be located in this path:

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini
```

But if you are on a Windows machine that would obviously be somewhere else. The key is to look for `conf.d` which holds additional configuration files loaded by PHP such as `apc.ini`.

Then restart your web server—Apache? IIS?—and you should be good.

Comment: You just made my day. APC on Google App Engine can be disabled using $ apc.enabled = "0"$ in php.ini file.